# How to execute redis-server.exe in Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I'm following this tutorial and faced the problem how to execute redis-server.exe in heroku.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv5jlmJs2sU&list=PLLRM7ROnmA9EnQmnfTgUzCfzbbnc-oEbZ&index=1

I added Heroku Redis on addons.

#### Procfile

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

#### Setting

```
import os
CACHES = {
    "default": {
         "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
         "LOCATION": os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'),
    }
}
.
.
.
```

I'm using windows.
Should I add something more on setting.py or Procfile?
I am a newbie btw. any suggestion and advice is welcome!
thank you!